# How to align a edit text in a linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a listview which have a textview, an edit text and a button in it. My view looks like this:

[image]

I want all the edit text to fall in one line. How can I do it? I've tried giving layout_weights in linear layout but it doesnt seem to work for me.

Here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/posmTypeLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posmDeploymentTypeTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Deployment Type"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp"
            android:layout_weight=".60"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

        <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
            android:id="@+id/posmDeploymentTypeSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Select Status"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight=".30"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"

            app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonRemovePOSMType"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:layout_weight=".10"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button2"

            app:srcCompat="@drawable/met_ic_close" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: set layout_width of children to 0dp ... this should force android to calculate width based on layout_weight

Comment: On what? I've already used it with the spinner, you can see my code.

Comment: add `android:gravity="center_vertical"` this in `LinerLayout` tag and `android:width="0dp"` in all child

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `layout_weight` property then always use `layout_width` as `0dp`

Please check below sample code, it's working perfect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/posmTypeLL"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/posmDeploymentTypeTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="Deployment Type"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_11ssp" />

    <com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.material.MaterialBetterSpinner
        android:id="@+id/posmDeploymentTypeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Select Status"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
        app:met_floatingLabel="normal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonRemovePOSMType"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_8sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_button2"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/met_ic_close" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! layout_weight is a neat trick but I totally forgot about the width set to 0 thing. I'll accept your answer in a while.